# Unlinking Account to Dropbox in iOS

Tags: ios, dropbox

I'm using Dropbox to sync files in my app. When try to unlink account to Dropbox, with below statement:

[[[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount] unlink];

iPhone 4S takes around 1 sec,  simulator a little big longer,3GS quite long, however for iPhone 5 it looks like its not working at all!. Could this be a memory issue? Am I missing something here?

Appreciate your advice!

Ethan

Answer (score 2):

from the dropbox [forum](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=98329). The unlinking does finish only after syncinc/downloading is complete.

Using GCD works for me.

```
- (void)dropboxLogout {
    self.isLogingOut = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        [[[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount] unlink];
        self.isLogingOut = NO;
    });
}
```

i use the `isLogingOut` flag to prevent my app from further communicating with the dropbox api while unlinking is in progress.

Comment: One problem is for iPhone 5 the unlinking is still not happening... is this an iPhone 5 issue?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code based on latest dropbox SDK:

```
- (IBAction)unlinkDropbox:(UIButton *)sender {
    DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];
    if (account) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
            [account unlink];
            // Shutdown and stop listening for changes to the datastores
            [[DBDatastoreManager sharedManager] shutDown];
            [[DBDatastoreManager sharedManager] removeObserver:self];

            // Use local datastores
            [DBDatastoreManager setSharedManager:[DBDatastoreManager localManagerForAccountManager:[DBAccountManager sharedManager]]];
        });
        self.isLinked = NO;
    }
```